# efficent way to save objects into binary files

Tags: c++, file, file-io, stl

I've a class that consists basically of a matrix of vectors: `vector< MyFeatVector<T> > m_vCells`, where the outer vector represents the matrix. Each element in this matrix is then a `vector` (I extended the `stl vector` class and named it `MyFeatVector<T>`).

I'm trying to code an efficient method to store objects of this class in binary files.
Up to now, I require three nested loops:

`foutput.write( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &(this->at(dy,dx,dz)) ), sizeof(T) );`

where `this->at(dy,dx,dz)` retrieves the `dz` element of the vector at position `[dy,dx]`.

Is there any possibility to store the `m_vCells` private member without using loops? I tried something like: `foutput.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(this->m_vCells[0])), (this->m_vCells.size())*sizeof(CFeatureVector<T>));` which seems not to work correctly. We can assume that all the vectors in this matrix have the same size, although a more general solution is also welcomed :-)

Furthermore, following my nested-loop implementation, storing objects of this class in binary files seem to require more physical space than storing the same objects in plain-text files. Which is a bit weird.

I was trying to follow the suggestion under http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/showthread.php?t=16465 but couldn't arrive into a proper solution.

Thanks!

Below a simplified example of my `serialization` and `unserialization` methods.

```
template < typename T >
bool MyFeatMatrix<T>::writeBinary( const string & ofile ){

    ofstream foutput(ofile.c_str(), ios::out|ios::binary);
    foutput.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->m_nHeight), sizeof(int));
    foutput.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->m_nWidth), sizeof(int));
    foutput.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->m_nDepth), sizeof(int));

    //foutput.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(this->m_vCells[0])), nSze*sizeof(CFeatureVector<T>));
    for(register int dy=0; dy < this->m_nHeight; dy++){
       for(register int dx=0; dx < this->m_nWidth; dx++){
          for(register int dz=0; dz < this->m_nDepth; dz++){
              foutput.write( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &(this->at(dy,dx,dz)) ), sizeof(T) );
          }
       }
    }

    foutput.close();
    return true;
}
```

```
template < typename T >
bool MyFeatMatrix<T>::readBinary( const string & ifile ){

    ifstream finput(ifile.c_str(), ios::in|ios::binary);

    int nHeight, nWidth, nDepth;
    finput.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&nHeight), sizeof(int));
    finput.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&nWidth), sizeof(int));
    finput.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&nDepth), sizeof(int));

    this->resize(nHeight, nWidth, nDepth);

    for(register int dy=0; dy < this->m_nHeight; dy++){
        for(register int dx=0; dx < this->m_nWidth; dx++){
            for(register int dz=0; dz < this->m_nDepth; dz++){
                finput.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &(this->at(dy,dx,dz)) ), sizeof(T) );
            }
        }
    }
    finput.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you write your own matrix class which keeps the data internally in a one-dimensional array (use `std::array`) which you can just write out directly?

Comment: Subclassing STL containers can be a bad idea. They were not designed for subclassing. Note, for example, that `std::vector` doesn't have a virtual destructor.

Comment: You might be interested in [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: @Kerrek SB, good suggestion but I need to consider the private members as I did.
@Martinho Fernandes, I'm not familiar with subclassing and for some reasons I can't use boost. Do you have another good webpointer?

Comment: @Peter: I don't understand which private members you mean. Is there any data you need to store apart from the matrix data? In any case, just store the matrix data in a 1D array and access it with suitable strides.

Comment: @Kerrek, with private member I mean the `m_vCells` vector.

Comment: @Peter: Isn't that part of the core data? I suggested folding that up into the 1D array. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Kerrek, yes, folding the data into a 1d array makes complete sense, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A most efficient method is to store the objects into an array (or contiguous space), then blast the buffer to the file.  An advantage is that the disk platters don't have waste time ramping up and also the writing can be performed contiguously instead of in random locations.

If this is your performance bottleneck, you may want to consider using multiple threads, one extra thread to handle the output.  Dump the objects into a buffer, set a flag, then the writing thread will handle the output, releaving your main task to perform more important tasks.

**Edit 1:  Serializing Example**
The following code has not been compiled and is for illustrative purposes only.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using std::ofstream;
using std::fill;

class binary_stream_interface
{
    virtual void    load_from_buffer(const unsigned char *& buf_ptr) = 0;
    virtual size_t  size_on_stream(void) const = 0;
    virtual void    store_to_buffer(unsigned char *& buf_ptr) const = 0;
};

struct Pet
    : public binary_stream_interface,
    max_name_length(32)
{
    std::string     name;
    unsigned int    age;
    const unsigned int  max_name_length;

    void    load_from_buffer(const unsigned char *& buf_ptr)
        {
            age = *((unsigned int *) buf_ptr);
            buf_ptr += sizeof(unsigned int);
            name = std::string((char *) buf_ptr);
            buf_ptr += max_name_length;
            return;
        }
    size_t  size_on_stream(void) const
    {
        return sizeof(unsigned int) + max_name_length;
    }
    void    store_to_buffer(unsigned char *& buf_ptr) const
    {
        *((unsigned int *) buf_ptr) = age;
        buf_ptr += sizeof(unsigned int);
        std::fill(buf_ptr, 0, max_name_length);
        strncpy((char *) buf_ptr, name.c_str(), max_name_length);
        buf_ptr += max_name_length;
        return;
    }
};


int main(void)
{
    Pet dog;
    dog.name = "Fido";
    dog.age = 5;
    ofstream    data_file("pet_data.bin", std::ios::binary);

    // Determine size of buffer
    size_t  buffer_size = dog.size_on_stream();

    // Allocate the buffer
    unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char [buffer_size];
    unsigned char * buf_ptr = buffer;

    // Write / store the object into the buffer.
    dog.store_to_buffer(buf_ptr);

    // Write the buffer to the file / stream.
    data_file.write((char *) buffer, buffer_size);

    data_file.close();
    delete [] buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

### Edit 2: A class with a vector of strings

```
class Many_Strings
    : public binary_stream_interface
{
    enum {MAX_STRING_SIZE = 32};

    size_t    size_on_stream(void) const
    {
        return m_string_container.size() * MAX_STRING_SIZE  // Total size of strings.
               + sizeof(size_t); // with room for the quantity variable.
    }

    void      store_to_buffer(unsigned char *& buf_ptr) const
    {
        // Treat the vector<string> as a variable length field.
        // Store the quantity of strings into the buffer,
        //     followed by the content.
        size_t string_quantity = m_string_container.size();
        *((size_t *) buf_ptr) = string_quantity;
        buf_ptr += sizeof(size_t);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < string_quantity; ++i)
        {
            // Each string is a fixed length field.
            // Pad with '\0' first, then copy the data.
            std::fill((char *)buf_ptr, 0, MAX_STRING_SIZE);
            strncpy(buf_ptr, m_string_container[i].c_str(), MAX_STRING_SIZE);
            buf_ptr += MAX_STRING_SIZE;
        }
    }
    void load_from_buffer(const unsigned char *& buf_ptr)
    {
        // The actual coding is left as an exercise for the reader.
        // Psuedo code:
        //     Clear / empty the string container.
        //     load the quantity variable.
        //     increment the buffer variable by the size of the quantity variable.
        //     for each new string (up to the quantity just read)
        //        load a temporary string from the buffer via buffer pointer.
        //        push the temporary string into the vector
        //        increment the buffer pointer by the MAX_STRING_SIZE.
        //      end-for
     }
     std::vector<std::string> m_string_container;
};
```

Comment: so i could create a temporary char array where I dump the whole content first, i.e. all elements of all vectors. Then, the array is stored into a file using one call to the `write` function. Is that correct?

Comment: @Peter: Yes you are correct.  I use `unsigned char` for my array.  I also created an interface for storing into a buffer, loading from a buffer and returning the size in the buffer.  This allows for easy concatination of objects into one large buffer.  The size function helps determine the needed buffer size.

Comment: thanks! I understood it then correctly. Do you might have some example code?

Comment: I added an example of a serializing interface. The interface allows for nested objects and multiple objects. First determine the size of the buffer by using `size_on_stream`. Second, allocate the buffer, using the result value. Third, store the object into the buffer. Lastly, write the buffer to the stream.

Comment: thanks for the illustration. As for the `size_on_stream()` part, you use the `max_name_length` variable, which was set manually to `32`, I guess this is the size of your structure, right? So, instead of hard-coding this variable, shall we consider sth. like sizeof(myClass)?

Comment: @Peter:  The `max_name_length` is the maximum field width of the text field.  DO NOT USE `sizeof(myClass)`.  The compiler is allowed to add padding between members.  Each data member should be written to the buffer independently.  This also allows for best use of buffer space.  This process also allows for Big Endian / Little Endian conversions, without the user of the object caring.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! So you're assuming that all `Pets names` are shorter than `32` characters, right? Could you please illustrate an example with stl vectors? For instance, imagine we have a new data member: `vector<string> m_VaccinationDate`, in which we store as a string a pet's vaccination date (`'dd/mm/year'`).

Comment: @Peter:  In messages, protocols and databases, the most efficient storage of text is with fixed length fields.  Internally, text should be represented by `std::string`.  With a fixed, maximum length field, a file can be read in blocks into memory.  With a variable length field, the field must be read character by character until a sentinel or terminator character is read.  The other option is to have the text preceeded by a numeric field indicating the size of the varying text field.

Comment: thanks! Could you still pls illustrate then an example for a `vector<string>` data member? We could imagine that each string has a fixed length of 32 characters. Best!

Comment: @Peter:  See Edit 2 in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to read [C++ FAQ on Serialization](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialization.html) and you can choose what best fits for your

When you're working with structures and classes, you've to take care of two things

- Pointers inside the class
- Padding bytes

Both of these could make some notorious results in your output. IMO, the object must implement to serialize and de-serialize the object. The object can know well about the structures, pointers data etc. So it can decide which format can be implemented efficiently.

You will have to iterate anyway or has to wrap it somewhere. Once you finished implementing the serialization and de-serialization function (either you can write using operators or functions). Especially when you're working with [stream objects, overloading << and >> operators](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/) would be easy to pass the object.

Regarding your question about using underlying pointers of vector, it might work if it's a single vector. But it's not a good idea in the other way.

---

Update according to the question update.

There are few things you should mind before overriding STL members. They're not really a good candidate for inheritance because it doesn't have any virtual destructors. If you're using basic data types and POD like structures it wont make much issues. But if you use it truly object oriented way, you may face some unpleasant behavior.

Regarding your code

- Why you're typecasting it to char*?
- The way you serialize the object is your choice. IMO what you did is a basic file write operation in the name of serialization.
- Serialization is down to the object. i.e the parameter 'T' in your template class. If you're using POD, or basic types no need of special synchronization. Otherwise you've to carefully choose the way to write the object.
- Choosing text format or binary format is your choice. Text format has always has a cost at the same time it's easy to manipulate it rather than binary format.

For example the following code is for simple read and write operation( in text format).

```
fstream fr("test.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary );
for( int i =0;i <_countof(arr);i++)
    fr << arr[i] << ' ';

fr.close();

fstream fw("test.txt", ios_base::in| ios_base::binary);

int j = 0;
while( fw.eof() || j < _countof(arrout))
{
    fw >> arrout[j++];
}
```

Comment: I have implemented my own `serialization` and `unserialization` methods. I've edited my original post and added the code. Is that the way you would suggest to do it?

Comment: thanks. I always thought that when dealing with `binary` files one needs to use the `read()` and `write()` functions instead of the `>>` and `<<` operators. Is is valid to do so? Furthermore, concerning the STL members, this would mean that as long as I choose `composite` over `inheritance` it should be ok, right? I'm not overwriting those classes, but also using internally their existent methods. In the case of a virtual destructor used in inheritance, if I use the `clear()` methods of the STL members in the destructors, it should be OK, right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that the most direct root to generate a binary file containing a vector is to memory map the file and place it in the mapped region.  As pointed out by [sarat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549731/efficent-way-to-save-objects-into-binary-files/6549854#6549854), you need to worry about how pointers are used within the class. But, [boost-interprocess library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/interprocess.html) has a [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container) on how to do this using their shared memory regions which include [memory mapped files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_mapped_files).

Answer (score 0):

First off, have you looked at [Boost.multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)? Always good to take something ready-made rather than reinventing the wheel.

That said, I'm not sure if this is helpful, but here's how I would implement the basic data structure, and it'd be fairly easy to serialize:

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t DIM1, size_t DIM2, size_t DIM3>
class ThreeDArray
{
  typedef std::array<T, DIM1 * DIM2 * DIM3> array_t;
  array_t m_data;

public:

  inline size_t size() const { return data.size(); }
  inline size_t byte_size() const  { return sizeof(T) * data.size(); }

  inline T & operator()(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k)
  {
     return m_data[i + j * DIM1 + k * DIM1 * DIM2];
  }

  inline const T & operator()(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) const
  {
     return m_data[i + j * DIM1 + k * DIM1 * DIM2];
  }

  inline const T * data() const { return m_data.data(); }
};
```

You can serialize the data buffer directly:

```
ThreeDArray<int, 4, 6 11> arr;
/* ... */
std::ofstream outfile("file.bin");
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(arr.data()), arr.byte_size());
```

Comment: thanks a lot! BTW, how would you overload the `operator()` in such a way to retrieve the sub-array at position `(i,j)`? e.g. `std::array<T> & operator()(size_t i, size_t j)`? Would it be also possible to completely remove the sub-array at position `(i,j)` from the original array?

Comment: @Peter: What is "the subarray"? There are many ways to choose a 2-dim subset of your 3-dim space, which one do you want? The general answer is, use the existing operator on (i,j,k) and fix one of the values appropriately...

Comment: a subarray can be understood as a vector in the R^DIM3 space. The idea is that given a pair of coordinates (i,j) corresponding to (rows,cols), I would like to retrieve all the values across the depth (DIM3).

Comment: @Peter: I see. It depends what you want to use that for. You could make a copy of that range, but that'd be expensive. For reading only you should probably design some custom iterators for those purposes.

Comment: I need basically to perform two operations. The first one is to delete the R^DIM3 vector at position `(i,j)`. Thus, the new `ThreeDArray` size will be `(DIM1 * DIM2 - 1) * DIM3`. The second operation is to assign/retrieve the R^DIM3 vector at position `(i,j)`. Do you mind in giving an example or maybe pointing a good web tutorial?

Comment: @Peter: What I would recommend is Boost.multi_array, as I said, which does already have all the features you require. Removing stuff will incur reallocations and moving of data. "Returning a vector" depends on whether you need a copy or just a read-only view of your fixed 3D data.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion onBoost.multi_array. As for your question on "Returning a vector", I need both a copy and also a read-only view. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Peter: For returning a copy, define a class for a 1D vector and copy the relevant data into it.